# Upload File using Postman

Tags: c#, postman, asp.net-core-2.1

I wrote a very simple POST api call just to test if the file was actually read in. I can't tell why but when I check the file instance while running the code, it is always passed as null. What is the cause of this problem? Postman or something in the code?

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost("fileupload")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            result.Add(await reader.ReadLineAsync());
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

And here are the POSTMAN settings I am using:

[image]

And here's how I'm uploading the file (assume that the filename is same as example.csv):

[image]

For uploading, I tried both binary and raw-data and still couldn't get the file to be read in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question!
Don't forget to add [FromForm] to your code!

```
[HttpPost("auxiliaryupload")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            result.Add(await reader.ReadLineAsync());
    }

    return Ok();
}
```